# UDP broadcasting on OSX fails, but works on Linux

Tags: macos, udp, broadcast

The following code does not work on OSX (it works fine on Linux); it (bind) fails with errno=49 `Can't assign requested address`.

```
    int fd, val;
    struct sockaddr_in sa;

    fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if(fd < 0)
        return -1;
    
    val = 1;
    if(setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &val, sizeof(val)) < 0)
        goto exit;

    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
    sa.sin_len = sizeof(sa);
    sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sa.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_BROADCAST);
    sa.sin_port = htons(50000);

    if(bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof(sa)))
        goto exit;
```

This bit of code *does* work on OSX if you specify an actual address other than `INADDR_BROADCAST` (or, at least `INADDR_ANY` works fine). I found that Darwin has this `sin_len` field that Linux does not, but setting or leaving it cleared has no effect.

Any idea what could be the trouble? If it were related to MACF I feel as if it would return a security-related error.

There are few example sources for OSX in general, and I did not find any for UDP broadcast.

---

It seems even `socat` can't do this properly on OSX. Incidentally it failed in the same way with the same error.

```
$ echo "TEST" | socat - UDP-DATAGRAM:255.255.255.255:50000,broadcast
2022/06/13 22:39:16 socat[7349] E sendto(5, 0x14100c000, 17, 0, LEN=16 AF=2 255.255.255.255: 50000, 16): Can't assign requested address
```

Comment: "Can't assign requested address" - this sounds like a bind() (or missing bind() ) problem. Find the local IP address of the interface where you want to send and try the following:

`echo "TEST" | socat - UDP-DATAGRAM:255.255.255.255:50000,broadcast,bind=<local-ip-of-interface>`

Comment: @dest-unreach That was it, actually (for `socat`). Incidentally, the code I posted above works properly to broadcast if I first bind to _anything_ other than `INADDR_ANY`, though this works on Linux as expected. Also perhaps it should be noted that after reflection I don't think binding to the broadcast address makes a whole lot of sense anyway (which is what my code above originally did) ... yet Linux appears unphased by the request.

Comment: So I think in the end binding to the broadcast address was the issue, with the remedy being to bind to a real interface address. And also that OSX does not appear to allow binding to all interfaces for broadcast. @dest-unreach if you want to post and answer I will accept it

Comment: I am glad that I could help you ;-)
I have no ambitions to write an article...